# Installing twitter bootstrap with Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-2

I am trying to install on an existing project Twitter Bootstrap

I tried to do that, following [this](https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails) :

```
group :assets do
  gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'
end
```

and I got that :

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    bootstrap-sass-rails (>= 0) java depends on
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0) java

    rails (= 2.3.14) java depends on
      actionpack (2.3.14)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    bootstrap-sass-rails (>= 0) java depends on
      rails (~> 3.1.3) java

    rails (2.3.14)
```

Knowing that when I run rails -v, I get rails 3.2.12. So, following the doc, I tried this

gem install bootstrap-sass-rails

I am told that the gem is successfully installed but I don't see any new file in my app folder. By the way, I tried to add in one of my stylesheet this

```
**/*
 *= require twitter/bootstrap
 */
**
```

But no bootstrap css seems to be called on my layouts. Could someone help ? Is this the right way to install Bootstrap ?

update : I have just noticed that in the gem file I have : gem "rails", "2.3.14"

Comment: If the application is not that huge, you could maybe consider moving to Rails 3 (or even Rails 4, which will get released soon). The reason is simple: All modern technologies won't be available for Rails 2, I don't think there will be much (any?!) tutorials on Bootstrap + Rails 2 on the web, 'cause bootstrap was released 1 year after Rails 3 release.

Comment: Sure, but I am working on gitorious and I don't know if I can upgrade to rails 3 or 4 that simply...

Comment: How about simply trying it? Create a new project there and set `gem 'rails', '3.2.12'` in your gemfile. Then run `bundle`. ... Have a look here: http://blog.gitorious.org/2013/01/29/gitorious-2-4-6-has-been-released/ .. you would have to run gitorious `next` branch. Maybe that's an option?

Comment: I've looked at google for Rails 2 + Bootstrap. There's nothing... Of course you could still do it without a gem, by including the CSS and JS by hand.

Comment: That's precisely what I was trying to do, and I added <link href="/var/www/gitorious/public/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">, which is the right absolute path, but in my console I don't even have a sign that the file is read ?? Am I missing something  ?

Comment: You may take Google Chrome or Firefox and open up the inspector. Then reload the page, there you can see which files the browser requested and which of those he didn't get (wrong path or sth. else).

Comment: Oh  I have something like 'a detached server' using ubymine on ubuntu, so I had to kill all processes to stop the server. So now it works, thanks !

Comment: Cool! :) Maybe Rails 3 will be available on gitorious when Rails 4 gets released :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For Rails 3:

I have bootstrap and fontawesome installed. Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

# ...

# jQuery
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Twitter Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'font-awesome-sass-rails'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
end
```

As you can see, I use a different gem for bootstrap. After editing Gemfile, just type `bundle` (or maybe `bundle update` is necessary)

---

This is my application.css.scss (under app/assets/stylesheets/):

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";
body { padding-top: 60px; }
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

---

And application.js (under app/assets/javascripts/):

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Sorry I am going to update my post, I am working on gitorious project and the gem file is rails 2.3.14. So your answer can't fit

Comment: Do you think the syntax to require twitter is correct (with all the stars symbols) ? Btw, suppose, I create a bootstrap.css.scss file, and add '@import "twitter/bootstrap";', where should I declare this file ?

Comment: If you're on rails 2, I think this may be different. I've posted my css.scss (using Rails 3.2.12)

Answer (score 2):

I have had issues following the "http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics"
as nothing I did looks as good as the output of the cast until I notice "Update February 6, 2013: The setup process for twitter-bootstrap-rails has changed since this episode. Check out the README for details on how to set it up."

So I followed to https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails and make the following installation steps and it works for me now:

1. Create a new rails 3.2.x app, 
   (if you rvm fan, work with rvm then)
   rails new Store
2. Edit Gemfile, and the following:
   gem "therubyracer"
   gem "less-rails"
   gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'#****doest work for me, so I need pull from the source as follow
   gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
3. run bundle install
4. Install bootstrap less, 
   rails generate bootstrap:install less
5. Install bootstrap static,
   rails generate bootstrap:install static
6. Copied and pasted the following lines into your "bootstrap_and_overrides.less",
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/reset.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/variables.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/mixins.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/scaffolding.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/grid.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/layouts.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/type.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/forms.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/wells.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/component-animations.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/buttons.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/close.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/navs.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/navbar.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/labels-badges.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/hero-unit.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/utilities.less";
   @import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";
7. Generate the layout either fixed or fluid, your choice.
8. Generate the model,
   rails g scaffold product name price:decimal --skip-stylesheets
   rake db:migrate
   rails g bootstrap:themed Products -f
9. run in development mode using WEBrick,
   rails s

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a rails thingy guy, but... did u go thru

http://railsapps.github.com/twitter-bootstrap-rails.html

http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/11/twitter-bootstrap-on-rails/

http://blog.robertosoares.me/blog/2012/08/17/integrating-twitter-bootstrap-with-ruby-on-rails/

It seemed pretty neat!

Comment: Sorry I have updated my post since I am using in fact rails 2.3.

Comment: The links are for rails.. soz i posted as "ruby". Edited now!